# Rspec : Only launching Firefox window. It is not loading the URL

Tags: rspec, watir-webdriver

Please help me discover why this is only launching the browser, not loading https://www.outbid.com/users/sign_in

```
require "rubygems"
require "rspec"
require 'watir-webdriver'

@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
describe "outbid login" do

before(:each) do
@browser.goto 'https://www.outbid.com/users/sign_in'
end


it "should succesfully login you in the outbid.com" do
@browser.text_field(:id=> "login_user_email").set 'outbiduser2@gmail.com'
@browser.text_field(:id=> "login_user_password").set 'c0mplex1234'
@browser.button(:value=> "Log in").click
@browser.close
end

end
```

Env:

Windows 7
32 BITS
Firefox 20 [Also tried in 8.0]
Installed  - Watir, Watir-Webdriver, Selenium-Webdriver, rspec.

Comment: If you want a good example of watir used within rspec, look at the watirspec project, it's all rspec tests

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get the following exception:

```
Failures:

  1) outbid login should succesfully login you in the outbid.com
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `goto' for nil:NilClass
     # stuff.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

The problem is that the browser you created is outside the scope of the test.

The line

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

needs to be within the test.

You would want to create it at the start of each test, so include it in the before-each block:

```
before(:each) do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  @browser.goto 'https://www.outbid.com/users/sign_in'
end
```

Comment: Still same issue.... problem is even it is not executing before(:each) do line.....browser is popping up for only @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox line...sot sure whether any compatibility issue is there or not.

Comment: How are you running the file? My guess is that it is being run in a way that does not request the tests to execute (ie it is just compiling of sorts).

Answer (score 0):

In general I like Justin's answer.   However if you want to save the time of opening and closing the browser before each test then what I would do is

1) create the browser object in the `before(:all)` section

2) in the `before(:each)` section or `after(:each)` ensure that you cleanup by doing something like hitting the logout page, so you don't start a test with a session going.

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest selenium jar from seleniumHQ.com and add the jar into your Class.